# How to create new JSString (or other type) from createObject?

Tags: jxbrowser

The last version of jxBrowser brings the createObject() method in JSContext.  I´d like to create a String (or other types) directly from java.  How can I use the createObject method to do that?

I´m able to create an empty object without problem and even set it´s property, but I don´t know how to create a String or Array or any other type.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Right now JSContext allows creating only JavaScript objects from Java. If you need to create a String or Array then you can use the following approach:

```
JSValue value = browser.executeJavaScriptAndReturnValue("'this is my string'");
JSString jsString = value.asString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I´ve just tried to hack a bit into it...

Doing:

```
obj = jscontext.createObject()
obj.setProperty("constructor", Array)
obj.setProperty("__proto__", Array)
```

Will create an object that acts like an Array in javascript (if calling eval on this object), although it is not a JSArray.

This approach does not work for String.  I guess String is a special type of constructor.